# Change <p> size on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m trying to increase the size of a `<p>` element, at the moment I have a code but this code changes the size for all the `<p>` elements in my page and what I want is give the user the freedom to change the size of the element he wants. So my question is: how can I do that? At the moment this is what I have:

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  var fontSize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
  fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
  $('p').css({
    'font-size': fontSize
  });
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  var fontSize = "8px";
  $('p').css({
    'font-size': fontSize
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<p>D</p>
<p>E</p>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the font-size of ONLY the clicked `<p>` try this:

```
$("p").click(function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
    $(this).css({'font-size':fontSize});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was going to be harder.

Comment: No prob, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$('p').css
```

to:

```
$(this).css
```

`$(this)` refers to the `<p>` being clicked, instead of `$('p')` which selects all paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$('p')` you should have to use `$(this)`. Because `$('p')` references all the `<p>` tag of dom and `$(this)` will the one which has been clicked. Please check below snippet.

```js
$("p").click(function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
    //In below line $(p) replaced with $(this)
    $(this).css({'font-size':fontSize});
});

$('#reset').click(function () {
  var fontSize = "8px";
  $('p').css({'font-size':fontSize});
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<p>D</p>
<p>E</p>


<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Why you have down voted? Please mention the reason so I can figure out accordingly.

Comment: You mention that `$(p) references the first <p> tag of dom` but this is wrong. `$('p')` selects _all_ <p> tags.

Comment: Also regarding `$(p)` vs `$("p")`. I'm not so familiar with jquery, but would `$(p)` not fail to select anything?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting `'p'` (which selects all elements with the given tag name), you can use the `this` keyword to target only the element that triggered the event.

```js
$("p").click(function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
    $(this).css({'font-size':fontSize});
  
    //console.log(this);
});

$('#reset').click(function () {
  var fontSize = "8px";
  $('p').css({'font-size':fontSize});
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<p>D</p>
<p>E</p>


<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be quite simple:

```
 $('p').css({'font-size':fontSize});
```

should be

```
  $(this).css({'font-size':fontSize});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
p{
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 12px;
}

</style>

<body>
<h1>Do it on click</h1>
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<p>D</p>
<p>E</p>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">



$("p").click(function(){//fire the function when click on any p element
   var thefontsize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));//get the current font size
   thefontsize = thefontsize+2;//increase the font size for each click
   $(this).css({"font-size":thefontsize+"px"}); //this keyword only focus on the element which user clicke, no all the elements.
});

$("#reset").click(function(){
 $("p").css({"font-size":"12px"});
});

</script>

</html>
```